# plotly: exposing the "config" object in the stored JSON string, for easier use with Plotly.JS functions

Tags: javascript, json, plotly, r-plotly, htmlwidgets

I don't know whether this is a plotly question or an [htmlwidgets](https://www.htmlwidgets.org/) question. Maybe it's both.

I am using R to make plotly widgets, which are -- when made from R -- also htmlwidgets. When making plotly widgets in this way, the resulting HTML contains a stringified JSON object that includes the data and some settings for the widget. But only some parts of this JSON object are easily accessed from a Javascript console. For example, the "data" and "layout" objects are easily accessed, but the "config" object is not. Why is that -- and is it possible to easily access the "config" object in some other way?

Here is an example, starting with R code that creates a Plotly widget:

```
  library(plotly)
  data(iris)
  myPlot <- plot_ly(
      x     = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width, 
      color = ~Species,
      data  = iris)
  myPlot$elementId <- "myExample"  
  myPlot
```

This code produces an HTML page that displays the plotly widget. The page contains a `<script type="application/json" data-for="myExample">` container, which in turn contains a stringified JSON object. Given the code above, the JSON object has this structure:

```
{
VALID (RFC 8259)
Formatted JSON Data
{
  "x":{
    "attrs":{},
    "layout":{},
    "config":{
      "showSendToCloud":false
    },
    "data":[],
    "highlight":{},
  },
  "evals":[],
  "jsHooks":[]
}
```

(For brevity, I've omitted a few objects in `x`. I'm also hiding the contents of most objects; for example, `attrs` and `layout` aren't really empty.)

From a Javascript console (e.g., in Chrome), it is then easy to access the "data" array and the "layout" object:

```
el = document.getElementById("myExample");
typeof el.data;    # "object"
el.data.length;    # 3
typeof el.layout;  # "object"
typeof el.config;  # "undefined"
```

I can get access to the data array just by typing `el.data`, and I can get access to the layout object in the same way. Why can't I get access to the config object just by typing `el.config`? And is there a way to make "config" as easily accessed as "data" and "layout"?

I ask because some Plotly.js functions, like `Plotly.react()`, take a "config" object. Functions like that would be easier to use if there were easy access to the "config" object.

I know that the "config" object can be accessed in other ways, e.g., with `JSON.parse()`. But the approach used above -- just call `el.data` or `el.layout` -- is much easier, which is why I would like to use it for the config data, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to access the "config" object, you may need to do so [the hard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61704340/revise-deeply-nested-json-array-in-dom), i.e., with `JSON.parse()`. But if you instead want only to update the config object, and then to update your Plotly figure, there are at least two alternatives:

1. Pass an unnamed object to `Plotly.react()`. Example: `Plotly.react(el.data, el.layout, {"showSendToCloud" : true} )`.
2. Use `Plotly.setPlotConfig()` followed by `Plotly.react().` Example:

```
    Plotly.setPlotConfig( { "showLink" : true } );
    Plotly.react(el, el.data, el.layout, {} );
```

(Curiously, `Plotly.setPlotConfig()` doesn't seem to have its own entry in the Plotly documentation, though it is mentioned in passing in other parts of the documentation.)